# How to make a proper Elapsed time? Python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

So far I did something like this:

```py
import datetime as dt
import time, sys
start = time.time() 

while True:
    now = time.time()
    delta = dt.timedelta(seconds=int(now - start))
    sys.stdout.write('\r\033[2K' + str(delta))
    time.sleep(.1)
```

But it prints it as a simple H:M:S method `0:11:11` and I need to do something like `3d, 21h, 46m, 12s` that automatically filters out some output if the value is still 0.
How can I do that?

Comment: it will include days if its longer than a day ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `datetime.now` instead of `time.time` and then convert it to `timedelta` .

```
start = dt.datetime.now()
now = dt.datetime.now()
print(frmtdelta(now - start))
```

You need to write a function to compute `hour`, `minute` and `second`. *(We have days in `timedelta`.)*

```
import datetime as dt
import time

def frmtdelta(delta):
    d = {"days": delta.days}
    d["hr"], rem = divmod(delta.seconds, 3600)
    d["min"], d["sec"] = divmod(rem, 60)
    return "{days}d, {hr}h, {min}m, {sec}s".format(**d)


start = time.time() 
while True:
    now = time.time()
    delta = dt.timedelta(seconds=int(now - start))
    print(frmtdelta(delta))
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Output:

```
0d, 0h, 0m, 0s
0d, 0h, 0m, 0s
0d, 0h, 0m, 0s
0d, 0h, 0m, 0s
0d, 0h, 0m, 0s
0d, 0h, 0m, 0s
0d, 0h, 0m, 0s
0d, 0h, 0m, 0s
0d, 0h, 0m, 0s
0d, 0h, 0m, 0s
0d, 0h, 0m, 1s
```

Comment: This answer does not filter out a value if the value is 0.

Comment: That was kind of you! I just was wondering regarding the questionline " that automatically filters out some output if the value is still 0. How can I do that?" But yes, it will fully and correctly display all the timevalues :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try building a string where if there is no value for a time you just do not append it to the string:

```
def build_time_string(delta):
    # Define all the available time data
    times = [
        ["d", delta.days],
        ["h", delta.hour],
        ["m", delta.minute],
        ["s", delta.second]
    ]

    # Build the list of values which are not 0
    time_string = []
    for time in times:
        if time[1] != 0:
            time_string.append(str(time[1] + time[0])

    # Join the string and add the comma seperator
    return ", ".join(time_string)
```

With this function you can edit your solution to:

```
import datetime as dt
import time, sys
start = time.time() 

while True:
    now = time.time()
    delta = dt.timedelta(seconds=int(now - start))
    sys.stdout.write(build_time_string(delta)
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'years'

Comment: Should be fixed now.